# How to create animated gender selection page?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I have built an app using Flutter. I want to create a gender selection page for it, currently I have a plain drop-down type button. I want to have an effect like this but I have no idea how to get this can anyone help?

[GIF of Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H89bF.gif)

```
    @override
  initState() {
    pageController;

    super.initState();
  }

  PageController? pageController =
      PageController(initialPage: 1, viewportFraction: .5);
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    TabController tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync:this);
    
   List genders = [
    Image.asset("assets/fitness_app/area1.png"),
    Image.asset("assets/fitness_app/area3.png")];

    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          premiumDialogue();
        },
        backgroundColor: primary,
        child: const Icon(
          Icons.add,
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: bgcolor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 70,
        leadingWidth: 65,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          "Home Workouts",
          style: h2black,
        ),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              controller: pageController,
              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: genders.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return genders[index];
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
       ],
      );
```

I have implemented this code but I was able to achieve this only.
[What I achieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeMcM.gif)

Comment: At least add some code to what you've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many approaches to achieving this you can your the pageview inside page view you can use the AnimatedContainer widget to animate the change in size and color of the selected image.

```
bool _isMaleSelected = false;

  bool _isFemaleSelected = false;


 void _selectMale() {
setState(() {
  _isMaleSelected = true;
  _isFemaleSelected = false;
});
```

}

```
void _selectFemale() {
setState(() {
  _isMaleSelected = false;
  _isFemaleSelected = true;
});
```

}

```
  return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    padding: padding as per your requirement,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: as per your requirement),
          height: _isMaleSelected ? height: height,
          width: _isMaleSelected ? width: width:
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: _isMaleSelected ? Colors as per your requirement: Colors as per your requirement,
           and decoration as per your need
          ),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: _selectMale,
            child: Image.asset(
              "your image path",
              height: height as per your requirement,
              width: width as per your requirement,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: height as per your requirement,
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: as per your requirement),
         height: _isFemaleSelected ? height as per your requirement: height as per your requirement,
          width: _isFemaleSelected ? width as per your requirement: width as per your requirement,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
             color: _isFemaleSelected ? Colors as per your requirement: Colors as per your requirement,
            decoration as per your need
          ),
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: _selectFemale,
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I used stack on top and removed the column widget and put animated containers inside and I was able to achieve it. Thanks again!